# Debug application on Jetty on Google App Engine (localhost)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jetty, dev-appserver

I am trying to run a localhost Dev App Engine running my application via Jetty. As seen the Dev App Engine starts:

```
[INFO] Sep 20, 2016 9:43:39 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
[INFO] INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
[INFO] Sep 20, 2016 9:43:39 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
[INFO] INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
[INFO] Sep 20, 2016 9:43:39 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
[INFO] INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

I try and access the admin page at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin:

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /_ah/admin. Reason:

    NOT_FOUND
Powered by Jetty://
```

I suspect my application has crashed on Jetty. Hows does one debug this?

I don't know what information is needed to you guys to help. Tell me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to update `appengine-maven-plugin` with the remote debugging  jvm argument as below.

   `<configuration>
                       <jvmFlags>
                           <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
                           <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                       </jvmFlags>
                   </configuration>`
2. Then run your dev server using `mvn appengine:devserver` command
3. Point your IDE to remote debugging port(5005)

Comment: You shot in the dark, and hit. Exactly the issue! The config was put to 8000 instead of 5005! Thanks!